# Minimum rectangles required to cover a given rectangular area

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have a rectangular area of dimension: `n*m`. I also have a smaller rectangle of dimension: `x*y`. What will be the minimum number of smaller rectangles required to cover all the area of the bigger rectangle?

It's not necessary to *pack* the smaller rectangles. They are allowed to overlap with each other, cross the borders of the bigger rectangle if required. The only requirement is that we have to use the fewest number of `x*y` rectangles.

Another thing is that we can rotate the smaller rectangles if required (90 degrees rotation I mean), to minimise the number.

n,m,x and y: all are natural numbers. x, y need not be factors of n,m.

I couldn't solve it in the time given, neither could I figure out an approach. I initiated by taking up different cases of n,m being divisible by x,y or not.

**update**

sample test cases:

- n*m = 3*3, x*y = 2*2. Result should be 4
- n*m = 5*6, x*y = 3*2. Result should be 5
- n*m = 68*68, x*y = 9*8. Result should be 65

Comment: can you provide sample testcase??

Comment: If it's an online judge problem, a link to the original problem is usually welcome.

Comment: @WhatsUp, it has been asked in a class.

Comment: @JishnuBanerjee. sample test case could be: n*m = 3*3, x*y = 2*2. The result should be 4

Comment: A more interesting example could be: `n * m = 5 * 6`, `x * y = 2 * 3`. The result should be `5`. The problem looks not so easy to me.

Comment: I expanded the answer, based on comments from @josch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(UPDATE: See newer version below.)*

I think (but I have no proof at this time) that irregular tilings can be discarded, and finding the optimal solution means finding the point at which to switch the direction of the tiles.

You start off with a basic grid like this:

[image: tiling - basic grid]

and the optimal solution will take one of these two forms:

[image: solution type 1] [image: solution type 2]

So for each of these points, you calculate the number of required tiles for both options:

[image: all grid points]

---

This is a very basic implementation. The "horizontal" and "vertical" values in the results are the number of tiles in the non-rotated zone (indicated in pink in the images).

The algorithm probably checks some things twice, and could use some memoization to speed it up.

*(Testing has shown that you need to run the algorithm a second time with the x and y parameter switched, and that checking both types of solution is indeed necessary.)*

```js
function rectangleCover(n, m, x, y, rotated) {
    var width = Math.ceil(n / x), height = Math.ceil(m / y);
    var cover = {num: width * height, rot: !!rotated, h: width, v: height, type: 1};
    for (var i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= height; j++) {
            var rect = i * j;

            var top = simpleCover(n, m - y * j, y, x);
            var side = simpleCover(n - x * i, y * j, y, x);
            var total = rect + side + top;
            if (total < cover.num) {
                cover = {num: total, rot: !!rotated, h: i, v: j, type: 1};
            }
            var top = simpleCover(x * i, m - y * j, y, x);
            var side = simpleCover(n - x * i, m, y, x);
            var total = rect + side + top;
            if (total < cover.num) {
                cover = {num: total, rot: !!rotated, h: i, v: j, type: 2};
            }
        }
    }
    if (!rotated && n != m &&  x != y) {
        var c = rectangleCover(n, m, y, x, true);
        if (c.num < cover.num) cover = c;
    }
    return cover;

    function simpleCover(n, m, x, y) {
        return (n > 0 && m > 0) ? Math.ceil(n / x) * Math.ceil(m / y) : 0;
    }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(rectangleCover(3, 3, 2, 2)) + "<br>");
document.write(JSON.stringify(rectangleCover(5, 6, 3, 2)) + "<br>");
document.write(JSON.stringify(rectangleCover(22, 18, 5, 3)) + "<br>");
document.write(JSON.stringify(rectangleCover(1000, 1000, 11, 17)));
```

This is the counter-example Evgeny Kluev provided: (68, 68, 9, 8) which returns 68 while there is a solution using just 65 rectangles, as demonstrated in this image:

[image: counter-example (68,68,9,8)]

---

**Update: improved algorithm**

The counter-example shows the way for a generalisation of the algorithm: work from the 4 corners, try all unique combinations of orientations, and every position of the borders a, b, c and d between the regions; if a rectangle is left uncovered in the middle, try both orientations to cover it:

[image: rectangle covering from the corners]

Below is a simple, unoptimised implementation of this idea; it probably checks some configurations multiple times, and it takes 6.5 seconds for the 11×17/1000×1000 test, but it finds the correct solution for the counter-example and the other tests from the previous version, so the logic seems sound.

[image: rotations]

These are the five rotations and the numbering of the regions used in the code. If the large rectangle is a square, only the first 3 rotations are checked; if the small rectangles are squares, only the first rotation is checked. X[i] and Y[i] are the size of the rectangles in region i, and w[i] and h[i] are the width and height of region i expressed in number of rectangles.

```js
function rectangleCover(n, m, x, y) {
    var X = [[x,x,x,y],[x,x,y,y],[x,y,x,y],[x,y,y,x],[x,y,y,y]];
    var Y = [[y,y,y,x],[y,y,x,x],[y,x,y,x],[y,x,x,y],[y,x,x,x]];
    var rotations = x == y ? 1 : n == m ? 3 : 5;
    var minimum = Math.ceil((n * m) / (x * y));
    var cover = simpleCover(n, m, x, y);

    for (var r = 0; r < rotations; r++) {
        for (var w0 = 0; w0 <= Math.ceil(n / X[r][0]); w0++) {
            var w1 = Math.ceil((n - w0 * X[r][0]) / X[r][1]);
            if (w1 < 0) w1 = 0;
            for (var h0 = 0; h0 <= Math.ceil(m / Y[r][0]); h0++) {
                var h3 = Math.ceil((m - h0 * Y[r][0]) / Y[r][3]);
                if (h3 < 0) h3 = 0;
                for (var w2 = 0; w2 <= Math.ceil(n / X[r][2]); w2++) {
                    var w3 = Math.ceil((n - w2 * X[r][2]) / X[r][3]);
                    if (w3 < 0) w3 = 0;
                    for (var h2 = 0; h2 <= Math.ceil(m / Y[r][2]); h2++) {
                        var h1 = Math.ceil((m - h2 * Y[r][2]) / Y[r][1]);
                        if (h1 < 0) h1 = 0;
                        var total = w0 * h0 + w1 * h1 + w2 * h2 + w3 * h3;
                        var X4 = w3 * X[r][3] - w0 * X[r][0];
                        var Y4 = h0 * Y[r][0] - h1 * Y[r][1];
                        if (X4 * Y4 > 0) {
                            total += simpleCover(Math.abs(X4), Math.abs(Y4), x, y);
                        }
                        if (total == minimum) return minimum;
                        if (total < cover) cover = total;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cover;

    function simpleCover(n, m, x, y) {
        return Math.min(Math.ceil(n / x) * Math.ceil(m / y),
                        Math.ceil(n / y) * Math.ceil(m / x));
    }
}

document.write("(3, 3, 2, 2) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(3, 3, 2, 2) + "<br>");
document.write("(5, 6, 3, 2) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(5, 6, 3, 2) + "<br>");
document.write("(22, 18, 5, 3) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(22, 18, 5, 3) + "<br>");
document.write("(68, 68, 8, 9) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(68, 68, 8, 9) + "<br>");
```

**Update: fixed calculation of center region**

As @josch pointed out in the comments, the calculation of the width and height of the center region 4 is not done correctly in the above code; Sometimes its size is overestimated, which results in the total number of rectangles being overestimated. An example where this happens is (1109, 783, 170, 257) which returns 23 while there exists a solution of 22. Below is a new code version with the correct calculation of the size of region 4.

```js
function rectangleCover(n, m, x, y) {
    var X = [[x,x,x,y],[x,x,y,y],[x,y,x,y],[x,y,y,x],[x,y,y,y]];
    var Y = [[y,y,y,x],[y,y,x,x],[y,x,y,x],[y,x,x,y],[y,x,x,x]];
    var rotations = x == y ? 1 : n == m ? 3 : 5;
    var minimum = Math.ceil((n * m) / (x * y));
    var cover = simpleCover(n, m, x, y);

    for (var r = 0; r < rotations; r++) {
        for (var w0 = 0; w0 <= Math.ceil(n / X[r][0]); w0++) {
            var w1 = Math.ceil((n - w0 * X[r][0]) / X[r][1]);
            if (w1 < 0) w1 = 0;
            for (var h0 = 0; h0 <= Math.ceil(m / Y[r][0]); h0++) {
                var h3 = Math.ceil((m - h0 * Y[r][0]) / Y[r][3]);
                if (h3 < 0) h3 = 0;
                for (var w2 = 0; w2 <= Math.ceil(n / X[r][2]); w2++) {
                    var w3 = Math.ceil((n - w2 * X[r][2]) / X[r][3]);
                    if (w3 < 0) w3 = 0;
                    for (var h2 = 0; h2 <= Math.ceil(m / Y[r][2]); h2++) {
                        var h1 = Math.ceil((m - h2 * Y[r][2]) / Y[r][1]);
                        if (h1 < 0) h1 = 0;
                        var total = w0 * h0 + w1 * h1 + w2 * h2 + w3 * h3;
                        var X4 = n - w0 * X[r][0] - w2 * X[r][2];
                        var Y4 = m - h1 * Y[r][1] - h3 * Y[r][3];
                        if (X4 > 0 && Y4 > 0) {
                            total += simpleCover(X4, Y4, x, y);
                        } else {
                            X4 = n - w1 * X[r][1] - w3 * X[r][3];
                            Y4 = m - h0 * Y[r][0] - h2 * Y[r][2];
                            if (X4 > 0 && Y4 > 0) {
                                total += simpleCover(X4, Y4, x, y);
                            }
                        }
                        if (total == minimum) return minimum;
                        if (total < cover) cover = total;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cover;

    function simpleCover(n, m, x, y) {
        return Math.min(Math.ceil(n / x) * Math.ceil(m / y),
                        Math.ceil(n / y) * Math.ceil(m / x));
    }
}

document.write("(3, 3, 2, 2) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(3, 3, 2, 2) + "<br>");
document.write("(5, 6, 3, 2) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(5, 6, 3, 2) + "<br>");
document.write("(22, 18, 5, 3) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(22, 18, 5, 3) + "<br>");
document.write("(68, 68, 9, 8) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(68, 68, 9, 8) + "<br>");
document.write("(1109, 783, 170, 257) &rarr; " + rectangleCover(1109, 783, 170, 257) + "<br>");
```

**Update: non-optimality and recursion**

It is indeed possible to create input for which the algorithm does not find the optimal solution. For the example (218, 196, 7, 15) it returns 408, but there is a solution with 407 rectangles. This solution has a center region sized 22×14, which can be covered by three 7×15 rectangles; however, the `simpleCover` function only checks options where all rectangles have the same orientation, so it only finds a solution with 4 rectangles for the center region.

[image: counter-example (218,196,15,7)]

This can of course be countered by using the algorithm recursively, and calling `rectangleCover` again for the center region. To avoid endless recursion, you should limit the recursions depth, and use `simpleCover` once you've reached a certain recursion level. To avoid the code becoming unusably slow, add memoization of intermediate results (but don't use results that were calculated in a deeper recursion level for a higher recursion level).

When adding one level of recursion and memoization of intermediate results, the algorithm finds the optimal solution of 407 for the example mentioned above, but of course takes a lot more time. Again, I have no proof that adding a certain recursion depth (or even unlimited recursion) will result in the algorithm being optimal.

Comment: Counter-example: `rectangleCover(68, 68, 9, 8)` finds a cover of 68 smaller rectangles. While optimal cover needs only 65 rectangles (group small rectangles into 4x4 array, put two such arrays to opposite corners of the square, then rotate the array and put two copies to the remaining corners, then cover hole in the middle with one more rectangle).

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Thanks. I'd been thinking about that kind of configuration, but hadn't found the right sizes. Could the algorithm be fixed by adding a check for this configuration, or do you think it points to a more fundamental flaw in the concept of only checking regular tilings?

Comment: Adding a check for this configuration would make algorithm much more complicated. This configuration could be considered as "regular", so it does not show a flaw in concept. But it shows that a proof is more valuable than algorithm itself.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev I came up with a generalised version which can solve the counter-example, and posted a code example. Still not sure this is optimal, but it seems implausible that you'd have to change the orientation of the rectangles more often than this to get an optimal tiling.

Comment: (I entirely missed `allowed to overlap`…)

Comment: @greybeard Yes, overlapping does make a difference, and the first version of the algorithm didn't really take that into account.

Comment: I tried scaling up Evgeny Kluev's counterexample by a factor of 9 in width and height to get the problem (612, 612, 9, 8), thinking that this would make an interesting test, since scaling up the 4 "corner blocks" of his solution by the same amount would then leave a 68x68 hole in the middle -- which could then be covered by 65 small rectangles, for a total of 64*9*9 + 65 = 5249 small rectangles.  But your code found a 5204-rect solution :)  (This is reasonable, since his solution has a waste of 72-16=56, so solutions as small as 5249 - 56 = 5193 might exist.)

Comment: This answer is wonderful. I'm about to add your algorithm to my own program after porting it to Python. How do you want to be attributed? As m69 or in another way?

Comment: @josch I'm glad you found it useful. "m69" is okay. But maybe add something that makes it clear that that is an SO username, like "m69 (Stack Overflow)" or "Stack Overflow user m69", or a link to this question or my profile page.

Comment: I might've found a small bug. The condition `if (X4 * Y4 > 0) {` will return true if X4 and Y4 are both negative. But if both are negative, then no additional cover is needed.

Comment: More is off. Consider `rectangleCover(594, 420, 170, 257)`. The best solution will have two portrait pages in the upper left and lower right and one landscape page in the upper right and lower left, each. The corners covering the upper left and lower right will overlap in the center, thus now extra cover in the center is needed. Still, `X4` and `Y4` compute positive results...

Comment: @josch Actually, `(594, 420, 170, 257)` returns the correct result of 6. At the point where (w*,h*) = (2,1),(1,1),(2,1),(1,1) the values of (X4,Y4) are (-83,87), so no extra center cover is added, and the function returns immediately because total = 6 = minimum.

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected. I had a bug in my Python port. But what about `(1109 783 170 257)` -- the javascript code finds a solution with 23 rectangles but there exists one with just 22 rectangles: third rotation and (2,2),(3,2),(2,2),(3,2) and 2 rectangles sideways to cover the hole in the center.

Comment: I think this might be the correct check for the center cover: `var W1 = n - w0 * X[r][0] - w2 * X[r][2]; var H1 = m - h0 * Y[r][0] - h2 * Y[r][2]; var W2 = n - w1 * X[r][1] - w3 * X[r][3]; var H2 = m - h1 * Y[r][1] - h3 * Y[r][3]; if (!(W1 < 0 && H1 < 0) && !(W2 < 0 && H2 < 0)) { var X4 = Math.max(W1, W2); var Y4 = Math.max(H1, H2); ...` The center cover is only computed if the diagonally opposite rectangles do not overlap in the center. The `Math.max` check takes care to choose the right size in both possible configurations: https://imgur.com/a/wzWCSP9

Comment: @josch Great, I'll take a better look at it later. (Btw, as I mentioned in the answer, I have no mathematical proof that this method is optimal, so you should probably treat it as a good heuristic.)

Comment: @josch I added a fixed code version. Thanks for investigating the error and pointing it out to me. What program are you using this in, btw?

Comment: Thanks, I like your improved version which avoids some unnecessary computations in certain cases. Yes, I'm aware that there is no mathematical proof of the optimality of this algorithm but this heuristic seems to be efficient enough. I'll leave a comment here once I publish my implementation of this algorithm. :)

Comment: @josch I added a counter-example that proves non-optimality, and the idea of using recursion to improve the results.

Comment: I published my code here: https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/plakativ/blob/master/plakativ.py#L91 I also had already suspected that a recursive approach might find a better solution in certain cases but I decided against it because for my purposes (making posters) a heuristic is sufficient.

Comment: @josch Great idea! Posters are indeed an obvious application of this algorithm.